# Maven versions ignored includesList

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin

When running versions:use-latest-versions, it seems to ignore my includesList sepecified on the commandline and attempts to update all depdencies.

```
mvn versions:use-latest-versions -DincludesList=com.mycompay.common:\* -DexcludeReactor=false  -DallowSnapshots=true -DallowMinorUpdates=true
```

Everything I can find in the documentation leads me to believe that specifying includes implies the exclusion of all else. Am I not picking this up correctly?

Comment: Just to clarify the source of the confusion and reason for the question - according to [this page](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html) the "includesList" is "Designed to allow specifing the set of includes from the command line." The accepted answer below is still correct in that using "includes" on the command line will work correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameter is `includes` not `includesList` so try this: (according doc [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html))

```
mvn versions:use-latest-versions -Dincludes=com.mycompay.common:* -DexcludeReactor=false  -DallowSnapshots=true -DallowMinorUpdates=true
```

Comment: One may need to also add `-DprocessParent=true` to upgrade POM parent dependencies. Otherwise parent references in POM are left unchanged.